# Запрос Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-filter

подскажите как правильно сделать запрос.
Ниже представлены модели

bank/models.py

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
      company = models.ForeignKey('Company.Company', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Фирма',
                            related_name='company')
      bank = models.ForeignKey('Bank', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Банк', related_name='bank')
      login_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Логин', null=False)
      password_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Пароль', null=False)
      date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
      date_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
      balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Bank(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название Банка')
```

Company/models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название фирмы')
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название на латинице', blank=True)
      inn = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='ИНН')
      okved = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='ОКВЭД')
      legal_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Юр.Адресс')
      legal_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Юр.Город')
      date_of_application = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Дата подачи')
      registration_date = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Дата регистрации')
      charter_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Номер устава')
      email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
      directors = models.ForeignKey(Director, null=True, verbose_name='Директор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      bankaccount = models.ForeignKey('bank.BankAccount', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Банк',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bankaccount')
```

Director/models.py

```
class Director(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='ФИО')
      inn = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='ИНН')
      date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=date.today, verbose_name='Дата рождения')
      place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Место рождения')
      id_passport = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Номер паспорта')
      date_of_issue = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Дата выдачи')
      issued_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Кем выдан')
      department_сode = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name='Код подразделения')
      street = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Улица')
      house = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Дом')
```

С помощью запроса:

```
BankAccount.objects.filter(bank_id=2).order_by().values('company__directors__name','company__name','login_bank', 'password_bank')

<QuerySet [
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР1**', 'company__name': **'ООО "ФИРМА1"'**, 'login_bank': 'login1', 'password_bank': 'pass1'}, 
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР1**', 'company__name': **'ООО "ФИРМА2"'**, 'login_bank': 'login1', 'password_bank': 'pass1'}, 
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР1**', 'company__name': **'ООО "ФИРМА3"'**, 'login_bank': 'login1', 'password_bank': 'pass1'}, 
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР2**', 'company__name': **'ООО "ФИРМА4"'**, 'login_bank': 'login2', 'password_bank': 'pass2'},
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР2**', 'company__name': **'ООО "ФИРМА5"'**, 'login_bank': 'login2', 'password_bank': 'pass2'}
]>
```

Вот теперь как их сгрупировать в:

```
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР1**','login_bank': 'login1', 'password_bank': 'pass1', 'company__name': {'id':[список BankAccount.company.pk ]''}, 
{'company__directors__name': '**ДИРЕКТОР2**','login_bank': 'login2', 'password_bank': 'pass2', 'company__name': {'id':[список BankAccount.company.pk ]''}
```

Буду очень признателен если поможите, или подскажите что почитать чтобы понять данного рода запросы.

PS.Сейчас БД - sqlite3

Comment: со sqlite не помогу. в постгес можно попробовать использовать ArrayAgg

Comment: Я как подумываю перейти на постгрес. Только все равно в голове не укладывается, как это реализовать. Если ты подскажешь как буду очень признателен

Comment: Ставишь постгресс по любому мануалу https://losst.ru/ustanovka-postgresql-ubuntu-16-04, меняешь конфиг в django например как https://www.djbook.ru/examples/77/ здесь. найстройки подключения к БД особо не менялись. Если будет ругаться - ставь все что требуют. и работать будет быстрее и больше возможностей

Comment: Cпасибо чуть позже займусь этим вопросом. Сейчас пока на sqlite посижу пока пишу